# How to ignore white space with regex?

Tags: regex

Here is my regex:

```
^(SK{1}[0-9]{8})$
```

But I want text like this:

```
SK 283 92758
SK 283 92 7 58
```

to be taken as this:

```
SK28392758
```

It is possible?

Comment: You need to match whitespace with `\s+` and remove it using regex-based search and replace. Or you can match non-whitespace parts into capturing groups, and then join them. Matching discontinuous text with regex is not possible. What language are you using?

Comment: It's completely based on the lang. @stribizhev jsut split on whitespace and join them according to an empty string.

Comment: you can get the matched value using .exec() method then you can apply replace simple white space with .replace(" ","");

Comment: In python `''.join(stri.split())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "optional" quantifier `?` for a space between each character:

```
^S ?K ?(\d ?){7}\d$
```

This allows an optional space between the characters.
To allow any number of spaces, replace every `?` with `*`.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/2iiN5vnAKB).

I also removed unnecessary brackets:

- `{1}` is pointless
- the brackets around the whole thing are unecessary; group `0`, which is the whole match, is always available is you absolutely need a capture group

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `^(SK{1}\s\d{3}\s\d{5})$` and use a `String.Replace` afterwards to remove the spaces.